# Batch script to move oldest file from one folder to other

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of files in my `c:\Test` folder. I want to move the oldest modified file (file which was modified first) to another location. I am very new to scripting.
Could you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
cd c:\Test
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W') do (
   move "%%a" C:\Another\Location
   goto continue
)
:continue
```

Comment: You forgot to use the variable name in the move command, Aacini.  It could work as it is by putting it before the goto command too - no need for a variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have cygwin `ls -ca` gives you a list of files sorted in order of modification time. Take the last one (tail -1) and move it where you want to.