# Batch file to delete oldest file in set of subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to modify the bath file as in the link below to search for the oldest file in a set of subfolders and delete it.

[Batch script to move oldest file from one folder to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17129965/batch-script-to-move-oldest-file-from-one-folder-to-other)

```
@echo off
cd c:\Test
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W') do (
   move "%%a" C:\Another\Location
   goto continue
)
:continue
```

Can any one help?

Further informations.

Comment: Do you want to delete **only one file**, the oldest, form all the files in the set of folders or do you want to delete **one file per folder**, the oldest in each folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
cd c:\Test
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W') do (
   del /Q /F "%%~dpfna"
   goto continue
)
:continue
```

?

Comment: Thanks for you help, this unfortunately doesn't work.  It appears to find the oldest files in the first alphabetically ordered folder and then deletes that one and if run again, deletes the next oldest in the same folder.  When that folder is empty it then progresses to the next alphabetically ordered folder and so on.  Not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: so you want to delete oldest file in each dir?

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion - do you want to move the file or delete it?

If you want to move the file, you'd need

```
move "%%a" "C:\Another\Location\%%a"
```

**provided** the destinaton directory exists.

or

```
move "%%a" C:\Another\Location\
```

or

```
move "%%a" C:\Another\Location
```

which would do the same thing **if** the directory `c:Another\Location` exists.

The `MOVE` will fail if `c:\another` does not exist, and will move the file to a file named `c:Another\Location` if the directory `c:Another` exists but not a directory `c:Another\Location`.

Probably the safest would be

```
md "C:\another\location" 2>nul
move "%%a" "C:\Another\Location\%%a"
```

where the `md` command will create the directory (which understandably wouldn't be done in a `delete oldest file` script. The `2>nul` suppresses error messages (such as 'directory already exists')